# How to use IFont and IStrings in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, com, marshalling, delphi-2010

I want to write a DCOM client/server in Delphi 2010 that uses IStrings to pass Memo1.Lines(as TStrings) as property in a test Server. The server has a TMemo component and I want to set or get its Memo1.Lines property through IMemoIntf of the server.
1-In RIDL editor IStrings was not accepted with out-of-the box Delphi 2010. So I registered stdvcl40.dll first and added it to the "uses" part of the editor to be able to add property of type IStrings.
2-Then I implemented two function Set_Text and Get_Text to set and get the Memo1.Lines of the server, as follows:

```
procedure TMemoIntf.Set_Text(const Value: IStrings);
begin
  SetOleStrings(Form1.GetText, Value);
end;


function TMemoIntf.Get_Text: IStrings;
begin
  GetOleStrings(Form1.GetText, Result);
end;
```

IMemoIntf is the interface that is been implemented by TMemoIntf. It is defined automatically as follows:

```
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IMemoIntf
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {2B6BD766-5FB6-413F-B8E2-4AB05D87E669}
// *********************************************************************//
  IMemoIntf = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{2B6BD766-5FB6-413F-B8E2-4AB05D87E669}']
    function Get_Text: IStrings; safecall;
    procedure Set_Text(const Value: IStrings); safecall;
    property Text: IStrings read Get_Text write Set_Text;
  end;
```

And TMemoIntf as follows:

```
TMemoIntf = class(TAutoObject, IMemoIntf)
protected
  function Get_Text: IStrings; safecall;
  procedure Set_Text(const Value: IStrings); safecall;
end;
```

When in client I call fMemo.Set_Text everything is fine and working properly, and the client sets the server Memo1 contents to its own, but when I call fMemo.Get_Text, to get the content of the server Memo1 contents, I get the following error message.

[Access violation at address ... in module 'combase.dll'.Read of address ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTZp4.png)

The client has a private field fMemo that shows the server and a Memo1 that is used to show the result of the Set/Get_Text calls.

```
TForm2 = class(TForm)
...
  btnSetText: TButton;
...
  btnGetText: TButton;
  Memo1: TMemo;
...
  procedure btnSetTextClick(Sender: TObject);
...
  procedure btnGetTextClick(Sender: TObject);
private
  fMemo : IMemoIntf;
end;

// it gives me the error
procedure TForm2.btnGetTextClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strings : IStrings;
begin
  Strings := fMemo.Get_Text;
  SetOleStrings(Memo1.Lines, Strings);
end;

// it works fine
procedure TForm2.btnSetTextClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strings : IStrings;
begin
  GetOleStrings(Memo1.Lines, Strings);
  fMemo.Set_Text(Strings);
end;
```

The same think apply to IFont, but OLE_COLOR is working flawlessly when I implement same things to work with TFont and TColor (I know OLE_COLOR is supported directly as an automation marshalled type, and differs from the two).
Am I doing it wrong or it is something in Delphi 2010?
How to mitigate the problem in Delphi 2010 with IFont and IStrings?

Comment: The above issue was tested in Windows 10-Pro 64bits, with "combase.dll" error. In Windows 7-Ultimate 32bits the error occurs in "ole32.dll". In this test also I need to register "stdvcl40.dll".

Comment: Ok, I have replaced "IStrings" with "TStrings.Text" in Get/Set functions in a new interface and used BSTR as it is supported by COM. This is a work-around and not a mitigation. Finding a reason should be helpful also for "IFont". Does anyone know a good reference for customize marshalling specially written for Delphi 2010? I am looking to implement new "IString" and "IFont" replacement. Or may be going through the source code, find the reason of this issue.

Comment: Hi David, Is there something wrong with my question or me? I didn't get any answer or comment on my question. Is that normal. Or there is something I need to do to get more hit? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok, I have found what was wrong, it was me. The definition of "__.ridl__" file is very important. for getter out parameter should be an "__IStrings**__" and for putter it should be "__IStrings*__". The compiler automatically update the "__TLB__" file and add a property to interface definition, and with the previous implementation of the "__IMemoIntf__" everything goes fine in both direction. I hope this help you. I don't know how to append, if someone interested show me how to append the complete project, to see what I have done. And someone to show me how to close this question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found what was wrong, it was me.

The definition of ".ridl" file is very important. For "getter function" the "out" parameter should be an "IStrings**" and for "putter function" it should be "IStrings*". The compiler automatically update the "TLB" file and add a property to interface definition, and with the previous implementation of the "IMemoIntf" everything goes fine in both direction.

I hope this help you. I don't know how to append, if someone interested show me how to append the complete project, to see what I have done.